# grep -rhi multiple strings from file

Tags: grep

Okay so I know i can do

```
grep -rhI "string1" .
```

but can I grab strings from a .txt file, so each string is on a new line, example

```
string1
string2
string3
```

as I have that many strings to process using

```
grep rhI "string1|string2|string3"
```

would be a pain..

Comment: Are you asking how to read search patterns from a file? if so, grep provides an option for that (`-f FILE` or `--file=FILE`). See `man grep`. Or are you asking how to output the matches one-per-line?

Comment: grep -Ff outputs false matches for me

Answer (score 0):

Put all the strings in one file as this:

```
$ cat strings
string1
string2
string3
```

And execute:

```
$ grep -rhIoFf strings
```

#### Edit

If it is not exactly `string1` what you need as output (the effect of -o) keep reading

---

Convert the list of strings in file strings (if they do not have spaces or new lines) to one string separated with `|` :

```
filter=$(printf "%s|" $(cat strings))
```

Then, use the string as the filter for grep :

```
grep -rhIE "${filter%?}"
```

Comment: if " o " is within - it only outputs " string1 " and not the rest of the line, but if I remove " o " it outputs false matches and pretty much dumps entire file into found? 

example of usage

grep -rhIFf string.txt C:/files/* > output.txt

Comment: well so search is " string1 " but my file contains unet:string1:random:example then output entire line because line contains " string1 "

Comment: just outputs a ton of lines that don't contain any of my strings, no idea why :S, is it possible if file.txt contains " string1 " its just outputting the entire file and not just the line its on? Like it's not reading per newline?

Comment: I'm using cygwin32 and filter=$(printf '%s|' $(<strings)) does nothing

Comment: @jakereading try filter=$(printf "%s|" $(cat strings))

Comment: Can You please post sample input and output required. we can assist you better